# How can I have active nav link in React with React Router Dom but just on big screens until my breakpoints kick in?

Tags: reactjs, router

I have declared function that will change Navigation Link style depending if it's active or not.

```
  const activeNavItem = ({ isActive }) => {
    return {
      padding: isActive ? "20px" : "0px",
      backgroundColor: isActive ? "#0000001a" : "transparent",
      borderRadius: isActive ? "8px" : "0px",
    };
  };
```

With `NavLink` I have declared this style to it

```
<NavLink style={activeNavItem} to="/">
```

But since I have Hamburger Menu this style still get applied, but I don't want it.

How can I have this `activeNavItem` but just on big screens?

Answer (score 1):

**Do this**

```
   {window.innerWidth>600? 

      //Styling for large active device
      <NavLink style={activeNavItem} to="/">
    :
  
      <NavLink style={mobileActiveStyling} to="/">
   }
```

**or**

```
let mediaWidth = 600;

<NavLink style={window.innerWidth > mediaWidth ? activeNavItem : 
mobileactiveNavItem } to="/">
```